# How can I make a query that allows the concatenation of two strings?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Sorry for the confusing question title, because I did not know how to summary my question in one sentence.

Basically, what I want to achieve is to ensure that the users can search what exactly they want in the database.

```
create table business
(post_code varchar2(8) not null,
company_name varchar2(50) not null,
code_name varchar2(58) constraint pk_business_compNo primary key,
address varchar2(100) not null);
```

This is a table where we keep information about companies.   `post_code` is the postcode of the company
`company_name` is the company name
`code_name` is the primary key of the table and it is also a concatenation of the `post_code` and `company_name`.
`address` is the address of the company

Then, I created a trigger to complete the concatenation

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_uppercas
BEFORE INSERT ON business
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF:NEW.code_name IS NULL THEN
        SELECT replace(upper(:new.post_code),' ' ,'')||replace(upper(:new.company_name),' ','')
            INTO :NEW.code_name FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

```
insert all
INTO business VALUES ('n1 9sV', 'HELLO WoRLD ltd', null, 'buckingham palace' )
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

so if I insert this data, the `code_name` value would be `N19SVHELLOWORLDLTD`

My question is that if it is possible to make a SQL query to search a company by prompting users to put the values for `company_name` and `post_code` and then concatenate these value and then make these values uppercase.  In this case, it should be guaranteed to find the value of `code_name` and the company we expect.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your table design is flawed. `code_name ` shouldn't be the primary key of the `business` table. It should not be alphanumeric and over and above identifying uniquely a `business`, shouldn't be dependant on other columns. Remember normalisation?. A Trigger for your case is also not worth it. It can be achieved using a Virtual column if needed. But, I would say you should rethink the design of your table by moving unrelated columns to other tables.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I do have the same idea as you.  however, they just want to keep the structure like that.  And one thing I forgot to tell is that the table should have another sequence number of the ```comp_no```.     ```comp_no``` and ```code_name``` will be the composite key

Comment: *"`comp_no` and `code_name` will be the composite key"* – really? How will `comp_no` fit into the query of `post_code` and `company_name`? Who is the *"they"* who is wedded to this dubious data model?

Comment: Yes, I am afraid it is. 
Also, because of the fact that most of the users do not know their ```comp_no``` and they use ```post_code``` and ```company_name``` to search the company record. Otherwise, I would definitely use ```comp_no``` to search for a company record. "they" refers to the people who created this table. I want to find out a solution to improve this design.

Comment: You cannot "improve this design" without changing the data model. Which you say "they" don't want to do. So it's a bit of a puzzle to understand what you're expecting from us.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the normalization of tables, to avoid unwanted steps. Add a numerical Pk in the table so that it is fed with an auto-incremental sequence.

```
Create Table Business(
  post_code varchar2(8) not null,
  company_name varchar2(50) not null,
  id Number constraint pk_business_compNo primary key,
  address varchar2(100) not null
);

CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

insert all
INTO business VALUES ('n1 9sV', 'HELLO WoRLD ltd', customers_seq.nextval, 'buckingham palace' )
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Now your filter would be company  name to look up the ID or another column

```
Select * From Business Where (company_name like '%' Or post_code like '%' Or address Like '%' );
```

In your model it would be like this (Bad practice):

```
Select  * 
From    Business 
Where   code_name Like '%'|| Param_user_company_name || '%' || Param_user_code_name || '%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  However, they want to keep the design of the table as it is.  And they would like to search for a company by prompting users to put company name and post code only.  
  And one thing I forgot to tell is that the table should have another sequence number of the ```comp_no```. ```comp_no``` and ```code_name``` will be the composite key